# Grunt Sass: change one folder name on destination path

Tags: sass, gruntjs

How to generate CSS files in a folder other than that of the SCSS source, but keeping a part of the tree of it?

Let me explain, I have different folders with several .scss sources:

```
resources/client-1/scss/app.scss
resources/client-2/scss/app.scss
```

I would like the CSS generated this place in the css folder and not scss. So:

```
resources/client-1/css/app.scss
resources/client-2/css/app.scss
```

But I would especially like to have a dynamic configuration, because the number of client-x folder will increase with time.

Any idea?
Thank.

---

**EDIT:**

My configuration using `grunt-sass` is currently as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
  options: {
    outputStyle: 'nested',
    precision: 3, 
    sourceMap: true
  },
  main: {
    files: {
      'resources/clients-1/css/style.css': ['resources/clients-1/scss/style.scss' ],
      'resources/clients-2/css/style.css': [ 'resources/clients-2/scss/style.scss' ]
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Can you show us your `Gruntfile.js`?

Answer (score 1):

You can [build the files object dynamically](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) (instead of using the [Files Object Format](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-object-format), which is what you're currently using), and utilize the [rename](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#the-rename-property) property to create the new destination path for each resultant `.css` files.

Replace your `files` property with the following instead:

```js
files: [{
  expand: true,
  cwd: 'resources',
  src: ['**/*.scss'],
  dest: 'resources/', // <-- Value must match `cwd` value and 
                      //     include trailing forward slash.
  ext: '.css',
  rename: function(dest, src) {
    var parts = src.split('/');
    parts.splice(1, 1, 'css');

    return dest + parts.join('/');
  }
}]
```

**Explanation:**

1. In the body of the `rename` function we firstly split the `src` path into an Array via the line which reads:

   ```js
   var parts = src.split('/');
   ```

   Given your example source path of `'resources/clients-1/scss/style.scss'`, this will result in an Array assigned to the `parts` variable like this:

   ```js
   ['clients-1', 'scss', 'style.scss']
   ```
2. We then use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) in the line reading:

   ```js
   parts.splice(1, 1, 'css');
   ```

   This replaces the value at index 1 (i.e. `'scss'`) with the given value of `'css'`. The `parts` Array now results in this:

   ```js
   ['clients-1', 'css', 'style.scss']
   ```
3. Finally, via the line which reads:

   ```js
   return dest + parts.join('/');
   ```

   We return from the function a new String for the `dest` path. Given the previous example the `dest` path will be this:

   ```js
   'resources/clients-1/css/style.css'
   ```

   Because the `ext` property has a value of `.css`, grunt replaces the original `.scss` extension name with `.css`.

---

**Note:**

If your `resources` folder has sub-folder(s) containing `.scss` files that you *don't* want to generate a `.css` file for you'll need to negate them using a [globbing pattern](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns). For example lets say your `resources` directory looks like this:

```
.
├── resources
│   ├── clients-1
│   │   └── scss
│   │      └── style.scss
│   ├── clients-2
│   │   └── scss
│   │      └── style.scss
│   ├── foo
│   │   └── scss
│   │      └── style.scss
│   └── quux
│       └── scss
│          └── style.scss
└── ...
```

And let's say you don't want `.css` files generated for the `.scss` files which exist in folders `foo` and `quux`, (i.e. you only want to process folders `clients-1` and `clients-2`).

Given such a situation you would need to change your `src` property in the code example provided above to:

```js
src: ['{,!(foo|quux)/**/}*.scss'],
```